# certbot creates a challenge owned by root:root and permissions 640 and apache can't access it - custom ACLs applied on parent directory

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, access-control-list, lets-encrypt, certbot

On my server I have special permissions that I set on my public_html folder.

First the sticky bit

```sh
chmod g+s /home/domain.com/public_html
```

Also default group permissions.

```sh
setfacl -m 'default:group::rwX' /home/domain.com/public_html
```

When I run my certbot command

```sh
certbot certonly \
        --webroot \
        -w /home/domain.com/public_html/ -d domain.com
```

certbot will create a .well-known/acme-challenge in the public_html folder with the correct permissions. It even keeps the correct group name. However, the acme challenge itself will have the following.

```
-rw-r-----  1 root                 root                   87 Feb  7 17:27 ELnik5A0krJsKUsL2If1mVfd2pSzWJAiSSjhA6h-f5E
```

It's owned by root and has the group root and can't be read by apache2. So the whole operation fails.

Adding --debug-challenges will allow it to pause so I can manually fix it, but I have a feeling renewing might be an issue.

What are my options here to fix this?

Comment: I would ask "why are you running certbot as root", you might want to consider running it as a more limited user. even if it does not solve your current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're merely overcomplicating things. Like a lot. No need to make webserver to deal with all of your special permissions and stuff: just make it it's own webroot for challenges with simple permissions (it will host the files like 0.0001% of its lifetime, and 99.9999% will just stay empty, so it can be considered totally safe):

for nginx it would be

```
    location ~* /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1;
        root /var/www/le;
        break;
    }
```

and for abandonware like (not sure, not using it for decades)

```
    Alias "/.well-known/acme-challenge" "/var/www/le"
```

(but seriously, get rid of the Apache, it's a museum stuff, most people got rid of it in the early '10s)

and then simply invoke the certbot with the new webroot:

`certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/le -d foo.bar`